# How to get Java boolean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I want to make an ajax call from a jsp :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function isTablePkUsedInFk(table_, pkVal) {

        var url_ = "<c:url value='/ajaxIsTablePkUsedInFk' />";

        var ret = $.ajax({
            data : {"table" : table_ , "pkVal" : pkVal},
            type : "POST",
            url  : url_,
            async: false
        }).responseText;

        ret = $.trim(ret);

        return ret;

    }

</script>
```

In the controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Home {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private UtilisateurDAO utilisateurDao;

    @Autowired
    private MenuDAO menuDao;

    @Autowired
    private DbDAO dbDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxIsTablePkUsedInFk", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public boolean ajaxIsTablePkUsedInFk(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String table = request.getParameter("table");
        String pkVal = request.getParameter("pkVal");
        return dbDao.isTablePkUsedInFk(table, pkVal);
    }

}
```

In runtime nothing happens when I call the javascript function `isTablePkUsedInFk` ! So how to get the Java boolean in javascript ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not return primitive from rest controller. Controller can returns a String object representing this Boolean's value.

```
@ResponseBody
public String ajaxIsTablePkUsedInFk(HttpServletRequest request) {
  ...
  return Boolean.toString(dbDao.isTablePkUsedInFk(table, pkVal));
}
```

Comment: Better to use [`Boolean.toString(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#toString-boolean-). No need to create a `Boolean` object just to get it stringified.

Comment: make sense... @Andreas

Comment: Can we return Boolean instead of boolean?

Comment: you can, in that case you need to explicitly specify `accept` header `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `response.tablePkUsedInFk` instead of `response.isTablePkUsedInFk`